# How can i heal... cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'jaxb:bindings'

Tags: eclipse, binding, jaxb, xsd

Having this .xjb file, Eclipse cmplains that it can't find the element *jaxb:bindings*. Where does this come from?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd" version="2.1">
    <jaxb:globalBindings>
        <jaxb:serializable uid="1" />
        <xjc:javaType name="java.lang.Integer" xmlType="xs:int" 
            adapter="com.foo.bar.jaxb.adapter.IntegerAdapter" />
        <xjc:javaType name="java.lang.Integer" xmlType="xs:integer" 
            adapter="com.foo.bar.jaxb.adapter.IntegerAdapter" />
        <xjc:javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:time"
            adapter="com.foo.bar.jaxb.adapter.TimeAdapter" />
        <xjc:javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:date"
            adapter="com.foo.bar.jaxb.adapter.DateAdapter" />
        <xjc:javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:dateTime"
            adapter="com.foo.bar.jaxb.adapter.DateTimeAdapter" />
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Eclipse complains in line 9:

> cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'jaxb:bindings'.

Why...and how can I can i fix teh problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this configuration in my projects.. (*maven & maven-jaxb2-plugin*)

```
<bindings version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net">

  <globalBindings>
        <xjc:serializable uid="12343" />
        <xjc:simple/>
  </globalBindings>

</bindings>
```

remove schema location declaration.

Comment: My mistake...I got the errors from a previously buill target folder. After running a maven build the error disappeared. The schemaLocation attribute mustn't be removed. Thank you.

Comment: Perfect :) could you close the topic? in order to make clear it :)